# Error in describe(iris$Sepal.Length) : could not find function "describe"

Tags: r, function, describe

psych installed
Warning messages:
1: package ‘psych’ was built under R version 3.6.3 
2: In p_load(psych) : Failed to install/load:
psych

Answer (score 1):

Your packages probably needs to be rebuilt under a higher R version. Try to run this code in your R console:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE,
                checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

**Explanation:** Some R packages need to be rebuilt after R update. If you don't do that, these packages throw an error that were built under an earlier version of R. Function [`update.packages()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/update.packages.html) downloads and installs packages which have a suitable later version on the repositories. The `ask` parameter prevents R from constantly asking you to confirm every update of every package, while the `checkBuilt` parameter is to reinstall all packages built under an earlier version of R.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! Really appreciate it

Comment: Just ran that chunk and now appears:
Error: failed to load external entity "http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/" when using p_help(psych) and still unable to run the describe function.

Comment: @mauricioperalc Hm, that's quite strange. It seems there could be problem in `pacman` package (do you use it?) or elsewhere rather than `psych` error. Maybe update your question above with a chunk of code that causes this error and copy complete error log here please. We'll see and try to help. (Yeah... and "unaccept" my answer so that the others can come here and help - I don't mind, really!)